# Long-running Chrome tabs are purging stylesheets from cache, causing the page to lose all styles when users re-focus

Tags: google-chrome, next.js, tailwind-css

My next.js based app (exported by SSG) serves styles from cachebusted urls, such as `_next/static/css/7bcc0ea16e62253d.css`. These change for new versions with style changes of course, and then older assets are gone.

I've noticed that for long-running and long-blurred tabs with my app open, upon refocus Chrome tried to reload the styles (presumable purged from memory by Chrome due to inactivity), it fails because of the older urls being 404 so users are stuck with an unstyled page - Much worse than just a FOUC.

Any way to force Chrome to not purge styles from memory, or a better way around this? Styles are tailwind-based, and loaded with link tags in the preload format: `<link rel="preload" href="/app/_next/static/css/7bcc0ea16e62253d.css" as="style">`.

I've looked into:

- Next.js configuration around prefetching and optimization
- MDN around the link tag and its newer attributes
- tailwind docs
- Searched for clues around Chrome's purging, to no avail.